# ASP.net Form Authentication allow access to "/" vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, webforms, authorization

I'm struggling to get around this problem with form authorization. I've got it all working as it should, people can only access the pages i specify apart from the root. By that i mean if they go to www.mysite.com they get the unauthorized access page but if i go directly to default.aspx, it works fine.

I'm still learning for please forgive me if it's something blatantly obvious :)

Here's my webconfig code:

```
<forms name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO" loginUrl="Logon.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" />
</authentication> 
<authorization>
<deny users="?" />
<allow users="*" />
</authorization>

</system.web>

<location path="Default.aspx">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="*" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

I've set my default doc in IIS to default.aspx but that's not fixed it.

How to i allow all user access to the root of my site?

Thanks all!

---

Update: I've tried this:

```
<location path="/">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

but i get a HTTP Error 500.19 :(

Updated: i've answered my own question - even though i cant answer it yet on here!

Well, it looks like i was doing it wrong - i've now changed to allow all pages and block the folder/pages i want like this:

```
<forms name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO" loginUrl="Logon.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" />
</authentication> 
<authorization>
<allow users="*" />
</authorization>

</system.web>


<location path="Admin">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="username"/> 

<deny users="*"/>  
</authorization>

</system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like i was doing it wrong - i've now changed to allow all pages and block the folder i want like this:

```
<forms name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO" loginUrl="Logon.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" />
</authentication> 
<authorization>
<allow users="*" />
</authorization>

</system.web>


<location path="Admin">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="username"/> 

    <deny users="*"/>  
  </authorization>

</system.web>
</location>
```